# Trouble adding test to output (enabled system administrators)

Tags: powershell, windows-administration

I'm having trouble with adding "=>" to each line of the output of the list of enabled administrators

```
$isEnabled = (Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {$_.Enabled}).Name
$localAdminUsers = (Get-CimInstance Win32_GroupUser | where {$_.GroupComponent -like "*admini*"} | select -ExpandProperty PartComponent).Name
$EnabledLocalAdmin = ($localAdminUsers | Where {$isEnabled -Contains $_}) #-join "`r`n"
for ($i=0; $i -lt $EnabledLocalAdmin.Count; $i++) { $EnabledLocalAdmins[$i] = "`n`t  => " + $EnabledLocalAdmin }
$EnabledLocalAdmins
```

Output from the above script:

```
=> Admin1 Admin2 admin3
```

The desired output should be:

```
=> Admin1
=> Admin2
=> Admin3
```

Comment: Apologies, the details have been cut off - here are the complete script details I am working with.

$isEnabled = (Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {$_.Enabled}).Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$EnabledLocalAdmin` is an *array* (contains *multiple* user names), so your output is to be expected, because when an array is *stringified*, its (stringified) elements are space-concatenated.<sup>[1]</sup>

A simple example:

```bash
$arr = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
"=> " + $arr  # -> '=> foo bar baz'
```

I suggest streamlining your code as follows, which also solves the problem:

```bash
# Get the usernames of all enabled local administrators.
$enabledLocalAdmins = 
  (
    Get-CimInstance Win32_GroupUser | 
    Where-Object GroupComponent -like *admini*
  ).PartComponent.Name |
  Where-Object { (Get-LocalUser $_).Enabled } 

# Display output.
$enabledLocalAdmins | ForEach-Object { "`n`t  => " + $_ }
```

---

<sup>[1] Technically, you can override this default separator via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), but that is rarely done in practice.</sup>